# JSON Auth validation from API

Tags: swift

I just discovered [this](https://reqres.in/) website and before I build my api I'm testing how to implement it on Swift. That website provides a POST response for Successful logins, these are the valid credentials:

```
{
    "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
    "password": "cityslicka"
}
```

and [this](https://reqres.in/api/login) is the url for the API

It seems like the actual login and user name is hidden there.
How can I implement in swift a code that tells me that ok, those credentials are correct, and return negative otherwise?
What is the simplest and secure way to do it?

Please put some comments on the code, I really need to learn, not only do it, because I'll work a lot on my app with the api.

This is my starting point, I know I have to create a model:

```
struct UserAuthJSONDataModel: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var email: String
    var password: String
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a call to the API. Currently it either gives back a token or the response "error":"user not found". You can run a simple if to see wether or not a token exists.

So in response to your comment currently when you open the link in the browser it is making the get call. You need to instead make the post call with the body. The first thing you will need is:

```
struct UserAuthCall: Codable {
    var email: String?
    var password: String?
}

struct UserAuthResponse: Codable {
    var token: String?
    var error: String?
}
```

Then you want to create your object like this:

```
let user = UserAuthCall(email: "email@email.com", password: "password")
```

Next we want to make the call. I recommend that you install the pod Alamofire because this is ideal for HTTPS calls. Here below I have a generic function which will allow you to pass any body and return any response and immediately decode it. You can use this in future as well.

```
func fetch<S: Codable, R: Codable>(_ url:String, send: S, of: R.Type, completion: @escaping (_ value: R) -> Void) {
    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: send, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: HTTPHeaders([HTTPHeader(name: "Content-Type", value: "application/json")])).responseDecodable(of: R.self) { (response) in
        guard let value = response.value else {print("issue"); return}
        completion(value)
    }
}
```

We will call the function like this:

```
fetch("https://reqres.in/api/login", send: user, of: UserAuthResponse.self) { (response) in
     // here we check if the token exists
     if response.token != nil {
         // user exists do whatever you want
     } else {
        // user does not exist try again
     }
}
```

Note: at the top of your file you will need to specify import Alamofire

I have tested and works perfectly with your credentials. One thing I will note though is that it seems that the API is indifferent to the password it is only checking for the existence of an email.

Comment: Oh! So it actually is asking for the token? If it matches the token? How will it know if the password is correct for the login? And yes, the question is about how I can call it and receive the response :) If you could add it that would be fantastic, please add some comments so I can learn the thought process

Comment: Ok cool, so 2 things: 1- Is this the way to authenticate users using API? So I check for the token and if it matches I let them in? 2- I implemented your code working but I get this message: `nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed` what is that?

Comment: @Arturo my email is on my GitHub https://github.com/williamfinn if you send me a screenshot of the code I can take a look

Comment: @Arturo or you can take this answer https://aiharasoft.com/wordpress/swift-tips/nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke-dlopen-libquic-failed/ which basically says ignore it (I get this message too)

Comment: Ok, I'll ignore it for now and thanks for the email offer. Btw any recommendation on how to check later on if the user is logged in? Do I have to store it somewhere so everytime the user posts something the login is checked?

Comment: @Arturo send email I will explain how to store